# Why does 0%0 result in 1?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, modulus

My Code:

```
long long difft, intrv ;

cout << "difft = " << difft << endl;
cout << "intrv = " << intrv << endl;
cout << "difft mod intrv = " << difft%intrv << endl;
```

Output:

```
 difft = 0
 intrv = 0
 difft mod intrv = 1
```

The result of 0%0 is zero, but in my code the result is "1", Why?

Comment: try to change your values to non-zero

Comment: Everything that has no explanation in C++, is because of undefined behavior :)

Comment: Actually 0%0 is undefined behaviour just becouse you cant divide by 0.

Comment: Division by zero is undefined not just in c++ but also in maths; as modolu is a special form of division your statement `0 % 0 = 0` is wrong. `x % 0` is like `x / 0` undefined.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: :) Yes I know, but I thought there is reason for different results.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, the example is sufficient and the OP explained the results and what they expected. It sounds like an honest question to me.

Comment: @Paranaix With respect to undefined in maths, it depends on your attitude to axioms relating to infinities. Some mathematicians **hate** them, and others are much more blasé. (With finite integers, UB is probably the best you can do. Depends on what the CPU maker thought was a good idea.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In *C++* the result of anything mod `0` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), from the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.6` *Multiplicative operators* paragraph *4* says (*emphasis mine*):

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. **If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined.**[...]

Also, using uninitialized variables is also undefined behavior, so the behavior of this program is unpredictable.

Comment: Yes, it is "undefined behavior", therefore there is no reason for different results.

Answer (score 6):

It is undefined behavior, because modulo involves a division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot divide by 0! It's a compiler fault, that it let you do this. That's why you see 1.

Comment: It's not the compiler's fault, as the standard does not mandate a diagnostic (let alone ill-formity). Actually, in the general case, the compiler _cannot_ prevent this. What if the divisor came from user input? Indeed, it sort of _does_ come from user input here, since it's the unspecified value of an uninitialised variable. There's no way the compiler could have predicted that the divisor was going to be 0.